# Best way to say doxygen "Do not parse \code section"?

Tags: markdown, doxygen

Doxygen version 1.8.12
Why doxygen strip @param, @example lines in my code block in .md (markdown) file? How to prevent this?

Example:

```
Before code text...
~~~~{.php}
namespace ModuleName\Model\ExternalApi\News;
class getList extends \ExternalApi\Model\AbstractMethods\AbstractGetList
{
    ...

    /**
    * Описание метода для справки на русском языке
    * #lang-en: Method description in English
    * #lang-de: Beschreibung des Verfahrens in Deutsch
    *
    * @param string $token Авторизационный токен
    * #lang-en: Authorization token
    * #lang-de: Autorisierungs-Token
    *
    * @param string $param1 Произвольный параметр
    * #lang-en: Custom option
    * #lang-de: Benutzerdefinierte Option
    *
    * @example 
    * GET /api/methods/news.getList?token=abcd&param1=1234
    * <pre>
    * {
    *    "response": {
    *        "news": [
    *            {
    *                "id": 1,
    *                "title": "Заголовок новости 1"
    *            },
    *            {
    *                "id": 2,
    *                "title": "Заголовок новости 2"
    *            },
    *        ]
    *    }
    * }
    * </pre>
    *
    * @return array массив со списком новостей. Описание ключей
    * response.news.id - ID новости
    * response.news.title - Название новости
    *
    * #lang-en: Array of news. Keys descriptions:
    * response.news.id - ID of news
    * response.news.title - Title of news
    *
    * #lang-de: Array von Nachrichten. Tastenbeschreibungen:
    * response.news.id - ID der Nachrichten
    * response.news.title - Titel der Nachrichten
    */
    protected function process($token, $param1)
    {
        //...
    }
}
~~~~
```

I want to see this code block without any changes in result documentation, is it real?

Comment: I think that there are 2 possibilities in your case. 1) replace the fenced code block by \verbatim ... \endverbatim block.  2) replace the fenced code block bu \code{.php} ... \endcode

Comment: thanks! it's work! I previously thought that "~~~~" synonyms to "\code".